# Check the current field value before updating in custom button

Tags: javascript, button

I am creating a custom button that will update the Status field on the Case object to "Resolved".  Before the field is updated, I would like to first check if the field already is set to "Resolved".  If so, then I would alert the user.  If not, the field update would carry on.  I have the below code in place but I am receiving the error "ReferenceError: Case is not defined" when the button is selected.  I believe I'm just missing a minor snippet of syntax - any help resolving this would be appreciated!

```
/* 
* Configuration: 
* Create new Detail Page Button for Account w/ Behavior "Execute JavaScript" 
* and Content Source "OnClick JavaScript" then add to page layout. 
*/ 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/27.0/connection.js")} 

try { 

var url = parent.location.href; 
var updateRecords = []; 
var update_Case = new sforce.SObject("Case__c"); 
update_Case.Id = "{!Case.Id}";  
update_Case.Status = 'Resolved'; 
updateRecords.push(update_Case); 

if ({!Case.Status}) { 

alert("The Case Status is already resolved") 

} 

else { 

result = sforce.connection.update(updateRecords); 

if ( !result[0].getBoolean("success") ) { 

var errors = result[0].errors; 
var errorMessages = errors.message; 
alert( errorMessages ); // display all validation errors 

} 

else { 

alert("Request has been submitted"); 
parent.location.href = url; 

} 

} 


} 

catch (e) { 

alert (e); 

}
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to wrap your field in quotes so that JavaScript properly interprets the merge output as a String:

```
if ("{!Case.Status}" === "Resolved") { 
   alert("The Case Status is already resolved") 
}
```